# Why say that H. A. Prichard's argument is not "formidable"?

Tags: ethics

In the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on H. A. Prichard, the author addresses Prichard's belief that obligations are predicates (properties) of agents, instead of actions:

> Prichard’s second argument is equally idiosyncratic. We can have an obligation to do an action long before the action is done. If so, the obligation cannot be a feature of the action, since it exists before the action does. It must be a feature of something else, if it is a feature of anything, and the obvious candidate is the agent.
>
> This argument impressed Prichard. But Broad wrote ‘I find it difficult to persuade myself that this argument is very formidable’ (1950, 555). I don’t myself think that the argument is especially formidable, exactly, but it does serve to prevent errors of various sorts, such as the error of thinking that deciding what to do is like choosing chocolates from a box, as if the actions between which one is choosing are somehow laid out before one in their full particularity, waiting to be chosen, that is, done. In the present case, the question is how to avoid the argument without going down Prichard’s route. It is true that there is no particular action that we are now obliged to do tomorrow; what we are obliged to do is only to act in a certain way; there will be a wide variety of actions that would meet that obligation, and we are not obliged to do one of them rather than any other. If we have to pay the money, it doesn’t matter, so far as that goes, how we go about doing it. But how does this help us understand what it is that is obligatory – the owner of the obligatoriness, as it were? It cannot belong to ‘acting in a certain way’. The most we could do would be to abandon the idea of obligatoriness as a character belonging to ‘acting in a way’ and think instead of something like ‘it is obligatory that p’, where p stands for ‘A Vs’. But even that doesn’t quite work, since it seems to specify a state of affairs or perhaps an event as obligatory, and this makes no sense at all. The only way to resolve the impasse is to take Prichard’s way out and award the obligation to the agent, yielding ‘A is obliged to V’ – which is where Prichard wanted to take us.

This reminds me of Onora O'Neill in *Constructions of Reason* where she says (forgive me for lacking a page-numbered citation) that practical reason does not take a given particular and subsume it under a general rule, since the relevant particular doesn't exist until the relevant action is taken (although a sufficiently vivid act of imagining a particular action in advance might "fill the slot," maybe). And all that seems very formidable to *me*, so to say. Or: **what does it mean to say that the argument isn't formidable?** That it isn't convincing? But https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#4.7 illustrates the issue fairly well, as a real issue it would appear, and ultimately I don't see how Prichard's conclusion is avoidable, and it doesn't even sound as if the author of the article on Prichard really avoids that conclusion.

Comment: First, obligation is not a "feature of" at all. It isn't a one place predicate, it is a two-place predicate:"X has an obligation to do Y". And second, X can have an obligation to do Y before doing Y, which means that a predicate (including a "feature"), which is out of time in virtue of being abstract, does not depend on its temporal arguments for "existence". Otherwise, red could not be a feature of this apple because it "existed before" this apple was even a bud on a tree, and was green before red. It takes a truly idiosyncratic ontology of relations to even make sense of Prichard's argument

Comment: Would Prichard's position be interpretable as: _"I have an obligation to do X," is prior to, "X is obligated"_? By comparison, responsibilities seem to attach first to agents, like we would tend to say (first), "I have a responsibility to do X," and only secondarily, "It would be responsible to do X." (And even then we'd more likely specify, "It would be responsible _of me_ to do X.") This doesn't turn obligations or responsibilities into one-place predicates, I would think. (But in deontic logic, it seems they do usually start out with, "It is obligatory that X," which looks one-place to me.)

Comment: Surface grammar is not always a guide to intended meaning. "X is obligatory" is used to indicate universalization of norms across agents (i.e. applying universal quantifier to one place of a predicate), which most ethical frameworks endorse, even if colloquial talk tends to shun passive voice. And, *pace* Prichard, there is no problem with inserting temporal objects into timeless predicates.

Comment: Would it be apropos to think of obligations, in full, as _three_-place predicates (or ternary operators)? Like, if obligations were always obligations of persons to persons, and then actions, e.g. "Sarah is under obligation to Mary to pay Mary's wages"?

Comment: Sure, but many place predicates can be reduced to two place ones using connectives and quantifiers. And I am not sure how this relates to Prichard's argument.